# reference a foreign key to a primary key within the same table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, foreign-key-relationship, create-table

I would like to reference a foreign key to a primary key within the same table, using the query design mode in ms access. This is what I tried to do:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( 
P_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
super_Id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employees(P_Id)
);
```

However I receive a syntax error (the word FOREGIN is highlighted). 
Is it at all possible to perform this task in ms access?

Edit: I switched to ANSI-92, and I also tried this format:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( 
P_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
CONSTRAINT super_Id  FOREIGN KEY (Employees)
);
```

but I still receive an error

Comment: Can you say why you are trying to do this?

Comment: Yes, what exactly is that you are trying to do? Maybe explain with simple words what you want, so we could give you a better solution.

Comment: It is an employee table. Each employee has a manager, who is also an employee.

Comment: Why not use the relationship window? A lot of DDL will only run with ADO in VBA.

Comment: As an aside, ANSI 92 can cause problems.

Comment: why should ANSI 92 cause problems? I don't want to use the relationship window since I want to practice writing SQL queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MS Access, you need to use `CONSTRAINT` keyword like:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( 
   P_Id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   Super_Id INTEGER NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY(P_Id),
   CONSTRAINT FK_SuperId FOREIGN KEY (Super_Id)
   REFERENCES Employees(P_Id)
);
```